Is rounding associative for scaled triangular numbers?
I've been pondering a problem related to splitting an array of $m$ elements into $n$ "mostly equal" buckets$^1$. My naive approach is to add a fraction of the size to a float index and just round when actually splitting:
split_fraction = m / n
split_index = m / n
for i from 1 to n - 1:
  array.split(round(split_index))
  split_index += split_fraction

I realized, however, that this assumes the rounded split indices don't skip a part in the middle or end which leads to my main question. For a non-triangular series, it's obvious that this can fail: $$round(1.49 + 2.49 + 3.49)=round(7.47)=7\\
round(1.49)+round(2.49)+round(3.49)=1+2+3=6$$
Can it be proven that the sum of the rounded split indices will equal the rounded sum? More formally:

Let $c=\frac{1}{n}$
Prove $round(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}c\cdot i)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}round(c\cdot i)$

The lefthand side can be easily simplified to $round(\displaystyle c\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2})=round(\frac{n+1}{2})$, but it's unclear to me how to analyze the rounding function.
1: By "mostly equal" I mean that each bucket has a size within 1 of every other bucket: $$|ceil(\frac{n}{m}) - floor(\frac{n}{m})| \leq 1$$
